# Lurton Sensing Switch electrical

Tags: electrical, switch

The Lutron sensing switch has 2 black wire and a white. My electrical box only has 1 white and 1 black. How do I wire this?

It’s a bathroom with a triple
Switch. Each switch has its own single black and white.

Comment: the switch has to get power from somewhere to run the motion sensor. The instructions indicate this is by using ground: Connect the permanent Hot black to black on Lutron and the second black to the white. Connect the ground.

Comment: *Some* switches allow ground instead of neutral. What is the model # of this switch?

Answer (score 2):

What you at the switch is what is called a switch loop.

They use the white(should be taped) wire as always hot and the black wire as switched hot to carried power back to the light.

Your Lutron switch requires a neutral wire(white) to work, most smart switches require neutral, but there are a few that don't.

You will need to bring a neutral wire to the switch from the light or return the new switch and buy one that does not need neutral.

To rewire you will probably need to replace the cable going to the switch now with one that has a black, white, and red wire.  Three wires plus a bare ground.  Ground wire is usually not counted in cables.

Comment: what switch loop ?

Answer (score 1):

You have *switch loops* with hot and switched hot but no neutral. That is very common on older houses and legal until relatively recently.

Smart switches often need neutral. As a result, code now requires neutral in most switch boxes.

Unfortunately, you can't install this switch without some rewiring, very likely having to run a new cable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multimeter (esential tool when working with electricity) use it.

You will find out that there is **no** 120 V between Black and White (because the white is not netrual).

The black in the box should have permanent 120 V against ground.

Connect that black with one of the Lutron blacks.

Connect the second black (on Lutron switch) to the White.

Connect the ground.

The switch has to get power from somewhere to run the motion sensor. The instructions indicate this is by using ground: